# Why does pattern "*.so?(.*)" produce a syntax error in a script but not on command line?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

The pattern is a little unusual because I added the trailing "?(.*)" portion. It works on command line as I expected but I get a syntax error for the same in a script.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
...
$ cat x.sh
touch a.so a.so.1
ls *.so?(.*)
rm *.so?(.*)
$ touch a.so a.so.1
$ ls *.so?(.*)
a.so  a.so.1
$ rm *.so?(.*)
$ ls
x.sh
$ bash x.sh
x.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
x.sh: line 2: `ls *.so?(.*)'
$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an extended glob but these aren't enabled by default within a script. In order to using them, they must be explicitly enabled. You can do so by adding this before the line:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

To disable them later on in the script, you can use `shopt -u extglob`.

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) rightly points out, this feature isn't enabled by default in the interactive shell, either. Presumably, this line is present either in one of your system-wide startup scripts or one of your personal ones.

Comment: They aren't enabled by default in an interactive shell, either; the user must have this line in a startup file somewhere.

Comment: I suspected that to be the case but I wasn't sure - I'll edit to include that info too, thanks.

Comment: I had to post another question http://askubuntu.com/q/634397/53613 to get the answer. My Ubuntu 14.04 ~/.bashrc sources /etc/bash_completion which sources /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion which executes "shopt -s extglob progcomp".

Comment: @John It seems like a separate question to me - this one was "why does it work in one place but not the other?", which I think I answered. I think that the other question is better suited to [ubuntu.se] (assuming that you're running Ubuntu), as it is a detail specific to that distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I had to go to Ask Ubuntu to get the answer to the original question (that you already answered). I meant I had to go to Ask Ubuntu to answer the issue raised here in the comments. Which is, where in my specific config is extglob being turned on?